# date format remain same in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

```
INSERT INTO DELLL (
DATETIMEMY) 
SELECT    to_date(to_char(SU_MODIFYDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'),'YYYY/MM/DD') AS DATETIMEMY
FROM SER_TBLSERVICES WHERE SVE_SERVICEID=422
```

**SU_MODIFYDATE = 01/18/2013**

but after insertion in DELLL date (DATETIMEMY) format still same is still same

**DATETIMEMY  = 01/18/2013**

Comment: How are you displaying that date? What's your default date format?

Comment: 2/15/2013 12:10:25 AM MM/DD/YYYY @Mat this is default date format

Answer (score 2):

you dont assign a format to a `DATE`. They are stored internally as a number and have no format. the format comes when you want to select the date. so in your case you should just do this:

first just insert the date as-is, do not try to convert it to a char and back again:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO DELLL (
  2  DATETIMEMY) SELECT SU_MODIFYDATE
  3  FROM SER_TBLSERVICES WHERE SVE_SERVICEID=422;

1 row created.
```

now to select it in a specific format, you can use `TO_CHAR` to format it.

```
SQL> select * from delll;

DATETIMEMY
----------
01/18/2013 <-- which isn't what you want to see, you wanted to see yyyy/mmm/dd. so...

SQL> select to_char(DATETIMEMY,'yyyy/mm/dd') DATETIMEMY from DELLL
  2  /

DATETIMEMY
----------
2013/01/18
```

or, to apply to all selects in that session that have a `date` datatype, you can alter the default display format:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy/mm/dd';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from delll;

DATETIMEMY
----------
2013/01/18
```

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor what is it you require?

Comment: Actually I want to to copy date from one table (SER_TBLSERVICES) , which date format is 1-15-2013 , into another table (DELLL) , which required a date format = 2013-15-1, in a single statement. as above.

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor as i've explained, dates do not have a format, so the insert (as both are `date` type) should just be to insert without any manipulation (unless you want to remove the time element, in which case apply a `trunc()` around the date field). The format is ONLY applicable to selects, which I've showed how to influence.

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT or SELECT in your example does not modify how a date is stored. Dates are formatted when you SELECT them, using your current connection format preferences/locale.

You are using TO_DATE, selecting that returned value is the same as with any other date, it will be formatted according to the locale.

Comment: I have used the to_date(to_char(SU_MODIFYDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'),'YYYY/MM/DD')

Comment: but dear, return date is also formatted to_char(SU_MODIFYDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD')

Comment: You are using TO_DATE, selecting that returned value is the same as with any other date, it will be formatted according to the locale. (so what is the solution, or your suggestion that fulfill my requirement)

Comment: You did not specify a requirement. If you want a string with a specific format, remove the to_date part.

Comment: if I remove to_date , then ORA-01861: literal does not match format string ;)

Comment: Ad I said, you cant change how a date is stored. You can only change how is presented when you make a select, by using to_char or changing the default format. Your example does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

DazzaL is right with his answer which discusses formatting, storage and retrieval of dates.

I would like to discuss what you are doing in your code.

Oracle stores dates upto precision of a seconds. In simple terms you can retrieve the date in `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS` format.

By issuing `to_date(to_char(SU_MODIFYDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'),'YYYY/MM/DD')` you are actually truncating the date up to the day part. So when you try to retrieve this value, the `HH24:MI:SS` part will have `00:00:00` because you have truncated the date.

If you want all the details (from year, month, day to hour, minute and seconds) from `SU_MODIFYDATE` to be inserted into the column in `DELLL`, you should just use

```
INSERT INTO DELLL (
DATETIMEMY) 
SELECT SU_MODIFYDATE AS DATETIMEMY
FROM SER_TBLSERVICES WHERE SVE_SERVICEID=422
```

This will ensure all parts of date in `SU_MODIFYDATE` column are inserted into the new column.

If you want to truncate the date, for example, upto the minute the use `to_date(to_char(SU_MODIFYDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI'),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')`

Likewise, you can truncate dates from year part upto the second part as per your choice.

If you want to insert truncated dates then you should use the query you already have. If you want to insert dates with all their parts then avoid truncating by using `to_char` and `to_date`.

Comment: or more simply `trunc(SU_MODIFYDATE, 'mi')` for example truncates a date to the minute without having to convert to char and back again.